# General::ivar: is not a valid variable

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation, warning-messages

```
pde = 1/Cosh[x]*D[Cosh[x]*D[T2[x, y], x], x] + 1/Sin[y]*D[Sin[y]*D[T2[x, y], y], y] == 0

sol[x0_] := NDSolve[{pde, T2[ArcTanh[x0], y] == 1, T2[xf, y] == 0}, T2[x, y], {x, ArcTanh[x0], 40}, {y, 0, 180 Degree}];

EG[x_, y_, x1_] := 1/(Cosh[x]^2 - Sin[y]^2)*((D[T2[x, y] /. sol[x1], x])^2 + (D[T2[x, y] /. sol[x1], y])^2)

EG[1, 1, 0.2]
```

> General::ivar: 5 is not a valid variable.

I can see the issue in EG is that its unable to take derivative first and then sub the value. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Why *aren't* you using different variables in `NDSolve[]`? Or, making them private with e.g. `Module[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noticed, this is a matter of evaluation order. The following is one relatively natural way to control the evaluation:

```
sol[x0_] := 
  NDSolve[{pde, T2[ArcTanh[x0], y] == 1, T2[xf, y] == 0}, 
   T2, {x, ArcTanh[x0], xf}, {y, 0, 180 Degree}][[1]]

expr[x_, y_] = 1/(Cosh[x]^2 - Sin[y]^2) #.# &@Grad[T2[x, y], {x, y}]

EG[x_, y_, x1_] := expr[x, y] /. sol[x1]
```

Note I've used `=` in definition of `expr`, `T2` instead of `T2[x, y]` as 2nd argument of `NDSolve`, and added `[[1]]` to remove a pair of `{}`.

Comment: I am getting an error when I try this "Plot[{EG[0.2, y, 0.2], EG[0.3, y, 0.3]}, {y, 0, 180 Degree}]"

Comment: @zhk Please show a complete code sample that reproduces the error. Currently `xf` is missing, and a `Degree` is probably missing inside `NDSolve`, too.

Comment: @zhk Please edit your question to correct all of the mistakes.

Comment: I am not doing anything extra with your code. I am just plotting using the above command I mentioned earlier along with xf=40, which returns `InterpolatingFunction::femdmval:`

Comment: @zhk Please calculate `ArcTanh[0.2]` and think about what's wrong.

Comment: `ArcTanh[0.2]>0.2` is the reason I am getting this error.

Comment: @zhk Yes, and you'll see the `General::ivar` warning again, but this time the reason is slightly different: it's because the `y` is _noticed_ by `Plot`. There're many possible solutions, here are two: 1. Control the evaluation again: `Plot[{EG[0.21, y, 0.2], EG[0.31, y, 0.3]} // Evaluate, {y, 0, 180 Degree}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 0]` 2. Use another variable name in `Plot`: `Plot[{EG[0.21, yy, 0.2], EG[0.31, yy, 0.3]}, {yy, 0, 180 Degree}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 0]`

Comment: One last thing, how to avoid the error in this `NN[x2_] := NIntegrate[EG[x, y, x2], {x, x2, xf}, {y, 0, 180 Degree}]`

Comment: @zhk Once again, use `Evaluate`, as I've done for `Plot`.